# Заполнить поля данными

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста, работаю с массивом data.vk.apps_connect в котором объекты с данными. В зависимости от кол-ва объектов создаю для каждого отдельный блок с полями, которые заполняются данными из этого массива. Проблема в том что сейчас я просто перезаписываю во все блоки одни и те же данные из последнего объекта. Как правильно обойти все блоки и в каждый записывать данные из нового объекта?
Так я обхожу исходный массив

```
    //Для каждого объекта создаётся блок с классом .panel.panel-default
    //в котором инпуты для данных

}
```

P.S. данные достаются нормально, проблема с обходом блоков и перезаписью содержимого тем что было в последнем объекте. Заранее спасибо

Comment: в данном цыкле вы ничего не создаете, просто каждый раз достаете контейнер `.soc-app.vk .panel.panel-default` и внутрь его вписываете данные и естественно что данные с последней итерации перезатрут то что было перед ними

Comment: А может сможете подсказать как обойти каждый такой контейнер и записать в него нужные данные?)

Comment: покажите `html` разметку

Comment: Может есть опечатки, но примерно так http://jsbin.com/yimuta/1/edit?html  все эти блоки (сейчас их 6) лежат в 1 родителе <div class"app"></div>

Comment: тоесть у вас 6 блоков ` <div class="clear panel panel-default active">` ? Они чем-то отличаются ?

Comment: пока что да, их количество приходит с сервера, потом будет больше 6, но неизвестно сколько

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так получилось сделать, но это при условии что хоть 1н блок `<div class="clear panel panel-default active">` у нас есть с самого начала, для первой итерации цикла заполняем его, для последующих, клонируем первый блок, вставляем в контейнер `.app` и заполняем его данные текущими данными :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var appDiv = $('.app');
  var panel = $('.panel.panel-default');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.arr.apps.length; i++) {
    var tmpContainer;
    if (i == 0) tmpContainer = panel;
    else {
      tmpContainer = panel.clone(true);
      appDiv.append(tmpContainer);
    }

    var app = data.arr.apps[i].app;
    var access = data.arr.apps[i].access;
    var service = data.arr.apps[i].service;
    var secure = data.arr.apps[i].secure;
    var app_access = data.arr.apps[i].access;

    tmpContainer.find('.app_id').html(app);
    tmpContainer.find('input[name="app"]').val(app);
    tmpContainer.find('input[name="app_access"]').val(app);
    tmpContainer.find('input[name="secure"]').val(secure);
    tmpContainer.find('input[name="service"]').val(service);
  }
});

var data = {
  arr: {
    apps: [{
        app: 1,
        access: 'adasda',
        service: '1233',
        secure: 'sk'
      },
      {
        app: 2,
        access: 'qqq',
        service: 'we33',
        secure: 'asdsddddd'
      },
      {
        app: 3,
        access: 'www',
        service: '333',
        secure: '3333'
      },
      {
        app: 4,
        access: '4444',
        service: '4444',
        secure: '4444'
      },
      {
        app: 5,
        access: '555',
        service: '5555',
        secure: '5555'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="app">
  <div class="clear panel panel-default active">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p>
        <span>ID приложения: <span class="app_id">-</span></span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h5>ID приложения</h5>
        <div class="inp-control">
          <input placeholder="ID приложения" type="text" name="app" data-id="app" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h5>Защищённый ключ</h5>
        <div class="inp-control">
          <input placeholder="Защищённый ключ" type="text" name="secure" data-id="secure" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <h5>Сервисный ключ доступа</h5>
        <div class="inp-control">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Сервисный ключ доступа" name="service" data-id="service" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <h5 class="key"><span>Ключ доступа</span></h5><a target="_blank" href="#" class="keyForAcess">нажмите для получения ключа доступа</a>
        <div class="inp-control">
          <input placeholder="Ключ доступа" type="text" name="app_access" data-id="app_access" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt1">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, чуток подправить и то что нужно, вы мой спаситель :-)